# How to expand a DIV without affecting other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm wondering how I could expand a 'div' without affecting the layout of the other elements in the page. Specifically, I'd like to achieve an effect similar to this - http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/categories/departments/kitchen/kitchen_int_lighting/. If you hover your mouse over any product, you'll see that the box expands showing more information; however, other elements such as the product image below is not affected by the expansion.

Answer (score 8):

use absolute position.
rather you can also achive the same effect by writing onhover event on the div with adding an additional div at that position with higher z-index.

Answer (score 1):

use absolute positioning, and then you can grow/shrink the div and it won't effect any other elements around it.

Answer (score 1):

Add `position:absolute;` to style of your div. This way it won't interfere with other elements but still overlap them, and you can specify any width and height to them.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely position your div and make sure the z-index is at the top level. It CAN be done using just CSS, but it'll probably be easier with js as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can use transform: scale(x); to grow/shrink the div without affecting the other elements.